Asymptotic growth of a set of functions
I need to test a condition on a function that must grow faster than $\Theta(n^2)$ but slower than $\Theta(n^2H_{n^2})$ when $n\to\infty$ ($H_{n}$ is the Harmonic Number, so it can be replaced by its asymptotic equivalent $\log(n)+\gamma$). For this purpose, I tried with the following form:
$$f(n)=n^2(H_{n^2})^\xi\quad\colon\xi\in[0,1]$$
As seen, when the parameter $\xi$ ranges from 0 to 1, it spans a set of functions $S$ that match the restriction $s(n)=O(n^2H_{n^2})-o(n^2)\enspace\forall s(n)\in S$. However, if we consider the set of all existing real functions whose growth lies in the set $O(n^2H_{n^2})-o(n^2)$, there might be more functions than the spanned from $f(n)$ with by varying its parameter.
Thus, is there any way to prove that $f(n)$ spans every function with a growth faster than $\Theta(n^2)$ but slower than $\Theta(n^2H_{n^2})$?

You need to define formally what does it mean that your functions span every function with growth between $\Theta(n^2)$ and $\Theta(n^2 H_{n^2})$. There are obviously functions like this that are not equal to $f(n)$ for every parameter $\theta$, such as $n^2 \log n$, $n^2 \log^{\sin^2 n} n$, or $n^2 \log \log n$.

@vladimir-lysikov With the form of $f(n)$ defined above, it doesn't seem to span all functions, like the ones you provided. The condition for a form of $f(n)$ to meet the spanning restriction is $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\forall\xi\in [0,1]\exists s(n)\in O(n^2H_{n^2})-o(n^2)$
